# If I'd like to indicate a duration of more than x years, can I write it as "+x years"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, writing-style, abbreviations

For instance, can I say "we provided +10 hours of programming services"?

Comment: Usually we say *over 10 hours* or *10+ hours*. Plus 10 is not a recognizable number.

Comment: Thank you @YosefBaskin :) Is this usage okay in general, even in contexts that don't involve durations (e.g., I worked with 10+ teams to complete this project)?

Comment: Since we do not have context, it is impossible to say what is OK. Is this formal, in-house chat, communications with a client? You see our difficulty?

Comment: Thank you @Cascabel :) This will be mainly used in a CV, so I guess that this makes the usage formal.

Comment: Oh my goodness..I am not sure if this is on-topic. Personally, I would use 10+. Most "linear" interviewers look only at the first page of a CV. You need to lay it all out in the first 20 seconds of a presentation. Otherwise "more than 10 hours", or "over 10 hours"....but "10 hours" is not really a long time. If it were something like 100 hours, well,  that would be different.

Comment: +10 hours.  You can say that.  But you will probably not be understood.

Comment: For a CV, I would use "over 10 hours" or "more than 10 hours".

Comment: Over the years, I have probably reviewed more than 2000 CVs. Unless it is from an astronaut describing EVA, saying _10+ hours_ is a meaningless annoyance, and sounds like groundless braggadocio from a recent under-grad.

Comment: @Cascabel I completely agree. Such usage in CVs or grant applications achieves the antagonised feeling of being both careless and pretentious. I don’t see why the statement is not the simple “more than ten”.

Comment: I wouldn’t put a number at all.  Instead, say what you did for them in those ten hours.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone! I appreciate your help!